# Setting the frame of a UITableViewCell with Snapkit

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit

I'm working on a project where I have a feed, made out of a `UITableView`. Within the cells `contentView`, I made a `UIView` with a white background to fake the padding on the trailing and leading side of the cell. That view is then positioned through `SnapKit`:

```
background.snp.makeConstraints { make in
     make.edges.equalToSuperview().inset(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 32, right: 16))
}
```

This works. However, if I try to get the height of the `background`, it gives me a height of `44`, which  is definitely not right. To clarify, I already called `setNeedsLayout()` and `layoutIfNeeded()` before attempting to get the height.

So my question is; is there a way to set the frame of a view, when setting constraints through `SnapKit`?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`? Or are you using a fixed height cell of 44? Just changing the size of a view (or other element) in a cell will **not** change the height of the cell --- unless you're using `.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` (along with not explicitly setting the rowHeight to a fixed value).

Comment: @DonMag `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is set, yes. There Is. however, an `estimatedRowHeight` set. If this isn't the case, the `background` doesn't even have a height

Comment: OK - are your rows showing up in your desired height?

Comment: hmmm.. also, you're setting the white "background view" to constrain to the sides of `contentView` ... but if you want that "background view" to actually **control** the height of the cell, you also have to set a height constraint on it. Otherwise, it will size ***itself*** based on the height of the cell, instead of setting the height of the cell based on ***its*** size.

Comment: @DonMag It's a edges constraint, so the `top` and `bottom` are also set. However, it's a view with a dynamic height, so it's kinda impossible to set the height right?

Comment: *"dynamic height"* ... well, then something is setting the height, right? Try a quick test... add a height constraint of something like 80 to the view, and see if it sizes the cell correctly.

Comment: @DonMag yep, that cuts off the view. however `cell.background.frame.size.height` still doesn't report the 80.

Comment: I'm assuming `cell.background` is the white view you added? At what point in your code are you looking at `cell.background.frame.size.height`?

Comment: @DonMag all the way down in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: OK - the frame is not set at that point, so what you'll see is the frame size as it was set in your prototype cell.